# Keyboard shortcuts not working in gnome-shell 3.2?

Tags: keyboard, gnome, shortcuts

I was wondering if keyboard shortcuts (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) support is removed from gnome shell 3.2?

If not then I'm missing something as I can't seem to use them.

Comment: Are only the F1, F2, etc shortcut keys not working? Ie: If you do crtl+alt+tab nothing happens?

Comment: sorry for incomplete info. but Alt+Tab, Alt+Ctrl+Tab, Alt+F9, Alt+F7 are working

Comment: Can it be that you have a "fn" key in your keyboard?

Comment: I do have fn key on my keyboard but F1, F2 are accessible without fn key fn+(Function key) gives me extra functionality like sleep, battery stats etc. And Alt+F2 used to work until gnome (not Unity/gnome-shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok so by default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't work in gnome shell [source: [http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html]](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html) 
 Here is solution they have provided:

> To fix it, open "System Settings" and under Keyboard > Shortcuts > System, click "Disabled" next to "Show the run command prompt" and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> - this should set <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> for running the command prompt.

Comment: Doesn't work, nothing happens when I click "Disabled" there.

Comment: Ugh. I felt pretty lame after looking right passed it for an hour... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had what I think was a similar issue although I'm not using gnome shell. It seems there may have been an issue in a recent update that was fixed in a more recent update. I was unable to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but after updating just now, I am able to use them again. You might ensure you are updated since it sounds as if you are using 11.10 beta and see if one of the 100 odd updates fixes your issue. Sorry for the random shot in the dark, but I'm fully functional again.

Comment: nope didn't work just tried sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade. Moreover on terminal mouse wheel scroll gives me previous commands rather than moving a page (previous behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is another odd behavior in the Shortcut assignment. How can you Disable again an assigned combination? I mean, I don't want no more use the Alt+F2 combination, how can I disable that? The only way I found was to "Reassing" the Alt+F2 combination to another Shortcut, so the previous assignment is disabled. But this is a workaround, not a feature.

Comment: Working perfectly on my machine, click on `Alt + F2` NOT on `Show the run command prompt` and then change or disable by pressing `Backspace`. And you should have started new question as right now I'm the only one (not whole community) being notified of your question. Have fun :)