# Alt+F2 stopped working in GNOME Shell

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, gnome

I just noticed that my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> no longer works in GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 11.10. It was working fine just last week . How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/65318/keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-in-gnome-shell-3-2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an odd issue where the keyboard shortcut to show the run command prompt becomes unset. To set it again open System Settings, choose the Keyboard panel under Hardware, and open the Shortcuts tab. From there, you can find the shortcut in the System section, and set it by clicking in the right column.

[image: Setting the run command prompt shortcut in the keyboard settings panel]

Comment: In `gnome-control-center` the Alt F2 shortcut is setup as in the image above; however pressing it still has no effect. Any other possibilities? I use cairo-dock rather than Unity for 11.10.

Comment: @Marcos Please post a separate question for your issue. This question is for GNOME Shell users.